# Using Tabs Navigation in Xamarin Android MvvmCross return incorrect index

Tags: xamarin.android, tabs, mvvmcross, fragmentpageradapter

I need advice from an MvvmCross expert!! I have recently taken over a codebase that is an Android/iOS app using Xamarin Native and MvvmCross. The app has a TabView as the main navigation pattern and it uses MvvmCross's MvxAppCompatViewPresenter for it. There are 5 tabs and the issue is that when navigating to any tab other that the first one, the correct view shows but the view model for a different view is loaded.

It is the Android side that is having the issue, and it uses a MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter to get and present the views. In this override method inside the PagerAdapter the fragment is loaded from a cached list, the view model is set and it is returned.

```
public override Fragment GetItem(int position, Fragment.SavedState fragmentSavedState = null)
{
    // todo: this is having problems, any tab other than the status (first) tab has a position 1 greater than its tab relation in the UI,
    // i.e. tab 2 has a position of 2 instead of 1 (tabs are 0 indexed)
    var frag = FragmentsInfo.ElementAt(position);
    var fragment = Fragment.Instantiate(_context, FragmentJavaName(frag.FragmentType));
    ((MvxFragment)fragment).DataContext = frag.ViewModel;

    return fragment;
}
```

[image]

As an example, when the user clicks on the "Logs" tab, the view is loaded but the GetItems method in the code shown above, "position" is one greater than it should be (i.e. should be 2 but is 3) and all the fragment information for the "Fuel" fragment is returned.

I am trying to track down a few things that I have yet to be able to find.

Where is the tab position set in the navigation pattern? I have yet to find a place where something like TabView.SetTab or the like happens. The closest thing I have found is a Navigation Attribute on the fragment, with IconTabPresentation being a subclass of MvxTabLayoutPresentationAttribute.

```
[IconTabPresentation(
    ActivityHostViewModelType = typeof(MainViewModel), 
    FragmentHostViewType = typeof(DashboardTabsFragment),
    TabLayoutResourceId = Resource.Id.tabs, 
    ViewPagerResourceId = Resource.Id.viewpager, 
    Title = "LogsTabFragment", 
    TabIconResourceId = Resource.Drawable.ic_assignment_white_24dp)]
[Register("app.LogsTabFragment")]
public class LogsTabFragment : BaseTabFragment<LogsTabViewModel>
{
    protected override int ResourcetId => Resource.Layout.fragment_tab_logs;
}
```

Where does the FragmentsInfo list (which belongs to the MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter) get set? When this code is debugged, it contains all the fragments and view models, but I can't find the place where that list is populated.

I know this is pretty general information but if someone familiar with the MvvmCross tab view navigation pattern could point me in the right direction it would be very helpful!

Comment: The `FragmentsInfo` property of `MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter` is set in it's constructor. You can check out the implementation over here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross.Android.Support/Fragment/MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.cs

Comment: Right. I figured as much. I debugged into the constructor of the subclass and watched the list pass though and get given to base. But that list only ever contains 1 item, not the 5 that the FragmentInfo has when GetItem hits.